# ImportError: No module named yaml with run_chroot_local (jenkins-script) fails

Tags: ros, jenkins, pre-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying out [run_chroot_local](http://wiki.ros.org/jenkins_tools#run_chroot_local), I get the following error ([full log](http://pastebin.com/Gepxp03b)):

```
$ run_chroot_local precise amd64 /home/rospasta/catkinws prerelease groovy openhrp3
  - ubuntu distro:  precise
  - architecture:   amd64
  - script:         prerelease
  - workspace:      /home/rospasta/catkinws
  - script args:    groovy openhrp3
:
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv  pbuilder-env.sh vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
+ export CCACHE_DIR=/var/cache/pbuilder/ccache
+ CCACHE_DIR=/var/cache/pbuilder/ccache
+ export PATH=/usr/lib/ccache:/home/rospasta/catkinws/devel/bin:/opt/ros/groovy/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
+ PATH=/usr/lib/ccache:/home/rospasta/catkinws/devel/bin:/opt/ros/groovy/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
:
============================================================
+ /home/rospasta/catkinws/jenkins_scripts/prerelease groovy openhrp3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rospasta/catkinws/jenkins_scripts/prerelease", line 2, in <module>
    from test_repositories import *
  File "/home/rospasta/catkinws/jenkins_scripts/test_repositories.py", line 6, in <module>
    import yaml
ImportError: No module named yaml
```

I first suspected that python's path wasn't set right, but [other modules](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/jenkins_scripts/blob/7e72b8ca0fa856376c6ad21bd69fd883137ecb63/test_repositories.py#L3) seem to be previously imported without an issue. Looking at [this thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/48151/jenkins_tool-run_chroot_local-doesnt-work/?answer=51832#post-id-51832) I now feel like looking into `pbuilder` but does anyone already have any idea? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/90836/importerror:-no-module-named-yaml-with-run_chroot_local-(jenkins-script)-fails/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have errors above. It looks like you are missing some dependencies on your local machine. Potentially apt-show-versions

```
 /usr/bin/chroot_create.sh: line 32: apt-show-versions: command not found
    + REPOSTAMP=
    + /bin/echo 'Repo stamp is '
    Repo stamp is
    + '[' 0 '!=' ']'
    /usr/bin/chroot_create.sh: line 36: [: 0: unary operator expected
```

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0